# bash robustness: what is a correct and portable way to trap for the purpose of an "on exit" cleanup routine?

Tags: bash, signals

When I create temporary files that I want removed when a script exits, I typically set a trap on EXIT. something like this:

```
function cleanup ()
{
   if [[ -d "$mytmp" ]]; then rm -rf --one-file-system -- "$mytmp" || :; fi
}

trap cleanup EXIT
...
```

I recently stumbled upon another script which sets things up slightly differently. It sets up a trap on EXIT, but *also* on actual signals, i.e.:

```
function cleanup () { : ... same as above ...; }
trap cleanup EXIT HUP INT QUIT TERM
```

I'm questioning whether the additional signals in the list are superfluous, or a strict improvement. Are there versions of bash that don't run the EXIT trap on certain signals?

In my experience, CTRL-C (SIGINT) a script will typically also invoke the EXIT trap, even without explicitly trapping on INT. Maybe I've always been lucky and it's just that a child gets killed by SIGINT first, and then the parent script exited with an error (because of `set -e` or another reason).

What's the best cleanup idiom, in terms of correctness and maybe portability?

**Update:**

This is tangential to my question, but one portability improvement, pointed out in the comments, is to define functions using the short form: `cleanup () { :; }` rather than `function cleanup () { :; }`. Thanks!

Comment: EXIT itself isn't a signal; it's a pseudosignal that the process "receives" prior to exiting, regardless of *why* it's exiting. That line should be superfluous.

Comment: oh, yes. I'll reword. It's a bash concept. It's just not clear from the manpage whether the EXIT trap is meant to be invoked on all exit conditions (error, success, and interrupts).

Comment: The man page says nothing about *why* the script exits, just "If a sigspec is EXIT (0) the command arg  is  executed  on  exit
              from  the shell."

Comment: There's sometimes a distinction when it comes to abnormal process termination, like described in `exit` or `atexit` (3 manpage). Maybe bash handles both the same way. I'll try a few things.

Comment: In terms of portability you'll want to ensure that whatever signals you are trapping are the same across platforms. You can check the signals by doing `trap -l`.

Comment: You're using both types of function declarations at the same time (`function` and `funcname ()`). You should use one or the other, [preferably the latter](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29).

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this quite recently on an old bash version (3.2, the one on MacOS from 2007...) and even there it's superfluous.

One could, however, argue that it's there for readability, to signal the reader: "there's no special behavior for any of the signals, just clean up and exit.", because if you have two `trap` statements referring to the same signal, the one which executed last will override.

Comment: oh. In both cases there's only one call to the `trap` builtin. I'll clarify.