# Issues with `trap cleanup INT EXIT` in BASH

Tags: bash, shell

I wanted my BASH script to end in a defined way doing some cleanup before exiting.
It's easy to do if the script runs until end, but it's getting tricky if the user is impatient and sends a `SIGINT` (^C).

So I added a `trap cleanup INT EXIT` (`cleanup` is my function to clean things up), and I thought things were OK (as `cleanup` would be called when the script exits, `cleanup` itself does not use `exit`).

But then I started a test adding `kill -INT $$; sleep 4` in the middle of the script, and I realized that `cleanup` is being called on `SIGINT`, but still the `sleep 4` was executed and at the end of my script `cleanup` was called a second time, something I did not intend.

So I wanted to "reset" the handlers at the end of my `cleanup` using `trap INT EXIT` as the manual page said the syntax is "trap [-lp] [[arg] sigspec ...]" (also saying: "*If arg is absent (and there is a single sigspec) or -, each specified signal is reset to its original disposition (the value it had upon entrance to the shell).*").

Interestingly that did not work as intended, so I used `trap '' INT EXIT` instead (The manual says: "*If arg is the null string the signal specified by  each sigspec is ignored by the shell and by the commands it invokes.*").
It would be a nice sub-question how to do it correctly, but let's ignore that right now.

If I modify my trap to `trap cleanup INT`, then the cleanup is executed immediately when receiving the `SIGINT`, and not when the script exits after the sleep eventually (`SIGINT` does not cause the script to exit early).

If I modify my trap to `trap cleanup EXIT`, then the cleanup is executed immediately when receiving the `SIGINT`, and the script ends after `cleanup` returned.

So the question is: Does `trap cleanup INT EXIT` make any sense (for cleanup purposes)?
It seems to me that `EXIT` includes the exits caused by any signal, too (I'm unsure whether that has been the case always).
Contrary trapping `SIGINT` would perform cleanup actions without actually causing the script to exit.

Is there a general agreed-on "cleanup trap pattern"?
(There is a similar question in [bash robustness: what is a correct and portable way to trap for the purpose of an "on exit" cleanup routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56604086/6607497), but it has no good answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell does not exit when a signal for which a trap has been set is received. So, the answer is **no**; `trap cleanup INT EXIT` does not make any sense for cleanup purposes, as it prevents SIGINT from interrupting the execution of the program, and hooks the cleanup routine to an event that doesn't warrant a cleanup anymore.

Not sure how agreed-upon, but this is how I do an automatic cleanup on normal or signal-driven termination:

```
cleanup() {
  # do the cleanup
}

trap cleanup EXIT
```